# Evolution of fruits throughout the history

Tags: data-request, images, food

I am looking for a dataset containing information regarding the evolution of each fruit throughout the history. Either images of fruits, or textual description of the fruit, or some more structured data, accompanied with some approximative date.

[Example](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-mind-blowing-facts-about-food/answer/Abdul-Ahad-M) of image descriptions for watermelon:

1645–72:

[image]

1824:

[image]

Current:

[image]

[Example](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-fruits-have-evovled-over-time-2014-10) of structured data describing watermelon:

[image]